# Magento 1.9.4.3 - Can't edit customer in Adminside or backend

Tags: magento-1.9, backend, customer-address, edit

I have many customers but when I edit customer thought 
backend like admin side but can't edit I face some issue 
and when Add New Address can't do anything see below snap..

[image]

[image]
when edit customer address can't be edit see above image and can't add the new address
see below snap I tried to find solutions but can't get the solution 
please give me a suggestion on how can I fix it ASAP.

Thank you.